# In debug mode Arraylist's logical structure is Array

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I run my tests in Spring Tool Suite 4 in debug. (On regular manual test of the code, everything works). In the code I initialize an ArrayList<>.

```
ArrayList<MyEntity> lst = new ArrayList<MyEntity>()
```

but the lst variable shows up as null and with the following error message:

```
Error   The method toArray() is undefined for the type Collection___
```

When I try to edit the logical structure it shows:

```
Type: Collection(java.util.Collection) Show As: Array[contributed by org.eclipse.jdt.debug] 
Preview: return toArray();
```

This issue only shows up when I try to debug my tests.

Comment: I have to admit: I still dont get what exactly you are doing, and what the problem is. Maybe this is one of the occasions where a screenshot is required....

Comment: this seems to be a bug with java 11 and eclipse https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=545739

Comment: this is the main bugreport https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543604

Comment: i am using openjdk 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have the same issue on several machines with a lot of different Oracle and OpenJDK JVMs.

- On the left, failure to display list elements in STS 4.2.2
- On the right, proper display in STS 3.9.5
- Both running on the same Windows machine and Oracle JDK 9.0.1

[Screen grab of STS 4.2.2 issue and STS 3.9.5 success with JDK 9.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI0Fz.jpg)

### Update

I just updated one of the failing STS4 installations to the latest version, and the problem seems to be gone. The version I received was:

- STS 4.3.0.RELEASE - Build Id 201906200901
- That release includes Eclipse JDT 3.18.0.v20190605-1800

Comment: I havent implemented on my own system, because we managed to avoid problems with this bug, but according to your picture you got the idea of the bug and you found an actual solution. Thank you :)